# Unreal engine pixel streaming deployment

Tags: unreal-engine5

What are the steps involved If want to deploy Unreal Engine Pixel Streaming to my domain with https. I have pixel streaming application running in GCP VM.

I was able to route traffic to my domain using http load balancer. I can see in pixel streaming infrastructure that config.json has a field useHTTPS whose default value is false. If I set it to true, it requires certificate to run , what type of certificate is required for that and how to get it ?